# problems with child components in Angular

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-components

Here is my project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/planificador?file=src/app/planificador/components/resumen/resumen.component.ts

I have a MainContentComponent (parent) within which I have several child components

[image: maincontent.html]

Now I see that inside ContratosComponent for example get proyectoId perfectly but in ResumenComponent I get undefined

[image: undefined]

[image: ngOnInit]

[image: inputs]

Any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run the stackblitz and it seems both components returned the proyectoId correctly - so I assume it might depend on some other things as well and not easily reproduced?

Your issue might be that the `proyecto$` observable comes from `BehaviourSubject`. This means that if not value was pushed to that subject, it will  emit null.

Your ngIf `<div *ngIf="proyecto$ | async as proyecto">` will return true as soon as the observable emits. So, if no proyecto was pushed to the `BehaviourSubject`, it will return true and `proyecto` will be null. This might be the cause of your issue.

Again, it's hard to say because it seems that there is some race condition that causes the issue to not always happen.

Comment: I have restarted stackblitz and now everything is fine, I do not understand it, but in the end things of the computer will be. Thanks...